# Share programming logic between Android an Web

Tags: javascript, java, android, typescript, web

I have an Android app and I'm making a web version currently.

In the app there are many utility files, let's say, for the sake of an example, a class that just formates a string in a certain way.

Is there any way to program this just once for both platforms (android and web), and not have separate implementations for Android in Java/Kotlin, and one for Web in JS/TS?

Answer (score -1):

if your web page is in html, you can use in your application the Jsoup library which allows you to extract and parse data from your html web page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).